# Getting a Pixel color from iPad Pro vs iPad

Tags: ios, swift

The following extension I found from another post works great getting pixel RGB values from a touch point on a screen image. It works on iPad but not on iPad Pro though. On a pro it returns the same fixed values regardless of touch location rather than the RGBA that's expected. Why does this not work properly on the pro? I suspect something to do with `CGBitmapInfo` settings but unable to figure it out from Apple's documentation.

```
extension UIImageView {
    func getPixelColorAt_ext(point:CGPoint) -> (clr: UIColor, red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {

    let pixel = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: 4)
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: pixel, width: 1, height: 1, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
    context!.translateBy(x: -point.x, y: -point.y)
    layer.render(in: context!)
    let r = Int(pixel[0])
    let g = Int(pixel[1])
    let b = Int(pixel[2])
    let color = UIColor(red: CGFloat(r)/255.0,
                        green: CGFloat(g)/255.0,
                        blue: CGFloat(b)/255.0,
                        alpha: 1.0)
    pixel.deallocate(capacity: 4)
    return (clr: color, red: r, green: g, blue: b)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with deallocate, this happens much faster on iPad Pro. Fixed by adding let r = Int(pixel[0]) etc. before calling pixel.deallocate as shown in the corrected version above.